# Grails 2.3.1 and burning image service plugin

Tags: grails, crop, grails-plugin, avatar, grails-2.3

I have installed and correctly configured `:burning-image:0.5.1` on my grails application.

I can upload images and retrieve them.

Now I want to retrieve a saved image and manipulate it.

The goal is to give a link to the registered user where he can crop his original avatar when he want.

Here is my configuration in **Config.groovy** for my user instance :

```
import pl.burningice.plugins.image.engines.scale.ScaleType

bi.User = [
    outputDir: 'upload/avatar',
    images: ['normal': [scale:[width: 800, height: 600, type: ScaleType.APPROXIMATE]],
              'small': [scale:[width:100, height:100, type:ScaleType.ACCURATE]]]
]
```

Here my field container in my User class :

```
import pl.burningice.plugins.image.ast.FileImageContainer

@FileImageContainer(field = 'avatar')
class User {
    /* ... */
}
```

I'm trying retrieve and manipulate 'normal' image for modify the 'small' one allowing my user to crop his original image :

```
imageUploadService.save(user, {avatar, name ->
})
```

But I get the following error : `Uploaded image is null`.

I [read the documentation](https://code.google.com/p/burningimage/) and found a lot of advices for manipulate image when they are uploaded, before saving, but not for manipulate existing image.

I definitely miss something but can't figure it out, any help is welcome.